# How to use Python to show only the letters from words with vowels

Tags: python, list

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"

word = "matt"
word = "james is funny"
cnt = 0

for v1 in VOWELS:
    print ("vowel", cnt)
    print("letter:", v1)
    cnt = cnt + 1
    for v1 in word:
        print ("location in string", cnt)
        print("letter:", v1)
        cnt = cnt + 1
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and it's driving me crazy. I just need python to print only the vowel letters in the words.

Comment: You can probably use Python's regex for this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the expected output?

Comment: instead of printing 
j
a
m
e
s

it would only print the vowels in that word and so forth so
a
e

Comment: `''.join([i for i in word if i in VOWELS])`

Comment: @MostlyHarmless the expected output has a space between 'a' and 'e'...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler hard to say based on his comment formatting, I interpreted it as him spacing out the word to highlight the inputs. Uncertain if requirements are "spaces persist" or "put a space between each letter of output", i.e. `' '.join` or `VOWELS+' '` is the proper fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward way:

- for each letter in the text

  - if it is a vowel, print it
  - otherwise print a space

Translates directly into Python (along with a tweak to keep everything on the same line when printing):

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"

word = "james is funny"

for letter in word:
    if letter in VOWELS:
        print(letter, end='')
    else:
        print(' ', end='')
```

Or the slightly more fancy way:

- Replace all non-vowels with spaces. Print the result

Using the regular expression pattern language:

```
import re

word = "james is funny"

new_word = re.sub('[^aeiou]', ' ', 'james is funny')

print new_word
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

word = "james is funny"
print re.sub('[^aeiou]','',word)

OUTPUT:

'aeiu'
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Print only the vowel letters in the words:

```
print ''.join(c for c in text if c in 'aeiou')
```

Print only words containing vowels:

```
words = text.split()
def containsVowel(word):
    any(c in word for c in 'aeiou')
words_with_vowels = [w for w in words if containsVowels(w)]
print words_with_vowels
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = "aeiou"
word = "james is funny and really fun!"
for v1 in range(len(vowels)):
    for v2 in range (len(word)):
        if vowels[v1] == word[v2]:
            print("location in string", v2)
            print("letter:", vowels[v1])
```

Python has a built in function which allows you to use strings as list and by using this you are able to loop through each letter of the string and compare with the vowels.

E.g.

```
vowels[0] = a
word[10] = u
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to find out the vowel from the word. Here passing the `word` to `re.findall()`, it will find all the vowels in the word and return as list of characters. We are joining the list to display as word.

```
import re
word = "james is funny"
k = re.findall(r'[aeiou]', word)
print ''.join(k)

Out: 'aeiu'
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.